# Maximization of ratio of two functionals

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I am trying to find a function prescribed in polar coordinates $r = f(\theta)$ that maximizes the following quantity

$$\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}r^3\cos\theta\, d\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}r^4\, d\theta}$$

subject to the constraint $r \leq R \quad \forall \theta \in [0,2\pi)$.

I don't even know where to begin to be honest. I went through a couple of books on calculus of variations. I haven't seen anything that comes close to the problem I have at hand.

Comment: Differentiate the given fraction.

Comment: @hjpotter92 differentiate with respect to what? $r$ is a function of $\theta$, not a constant.

Comment: @Surb If you read the sentence of the question, you will see that it has already been pointed out. It is common practice to drop the $x$ from the notation $y(x)$ once it has been made clear that $y$ is a function of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the maximum is $+\infty$. Consider for example $r=f(\theta)=\epsilon |\cos(\theta/2)|$. Then
$$
\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}r^3\cos\theta d\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}r^4 d\theta}=\frac{32}{15\pi\epsilon}
$$
and this tends to $+\infty$ as $\epsilon$ goes to $ 0^+$.